# Trouble handling zip files?

Tags: zip, htaccess

I'm trying to send a zip file to someone, but I'm having a lot more trouble with it than I should. I tried uploading it to 4shared, mediafire, and megaupload, but all uploads failed multiple times. I'm pretty sure it's because I have two routers set up, as I never had a problem with uploads before. I'm not sure if anyone here knows anything about what might be wrong, but if you do that would be great.

What I'm trying right now is uploading the file to a website and then using that. It uploads fine and when I download with filezilla from the site, the original file and the file I downloaded are identical. When I download using any browser, the downloaded zip is 47,468,764 bytes and the original is 90,476,482 bytes. HxD says the two files are identical except for the fact that the second is just about half the size.

Is this something to do with, or something that could be fixed with the .htaccess file?

Comment: Wow... -_-  You got me here.  One thought... I think AIM used to allow file transfers much like DCCs on IRC.  IRC would be another easy option.  Lastly, I THINK Windows Remote Assistance will allow File Transfers but I can't recall and I can't set one up right now lol.  I don't really think this has anything to do with your router because it should either route or it shouldn't... I can't figure what would let it rout but only half of it... (not saying that ain't POSSIBLE only that I have no idea how)

Comment: Have you tried DropBox?

Comment: It's not a matter of transferring the file, but getting it online.

Comment: Um... but... isn't "getting the file online" = transferring it? :)  Seriously though my point is only that if you want to get the file from A to B... do you REALLY care that much HOW exactly you accomplish so long as it is successful?  And for that matter, an end point to end point transfer vs a transfer to an online repository where another party can then go tgo that repository and download (aka transfer it to their system lol) then I'd think that was better/easier.  Just a suggestion though.  Maybe you have a reason to want this specific method.

Comment: Yeah, I need to share the file with multiple people and at different times.